# android studio 2.3.3 sdk manager show package details not working

Tags: android, android-studio

As i updated Android Studio to 2.3, i am facing this issue of SDK Manager. Due to which I am unable to update my SDK.

Here is a screen shot of Android Studio SDK manager where you can see that SHOW DETAILS option is frozen
 [image: Here is a screen shot of Android Studio SDK manager where you can see that SHOW DETAILS option is frozen]

Comment: At first remove space.

Comment: Do you see the warning message in the middle of the window?

Comment: No I don't see any warning. @Amiya I'll remove spaces and try again..

Answer (score 1):

I simply uninstalled Android Studio completely, downloaded the latest version of Android Studio & reinstalled it. And now every thing is working fine.